# Regex to find and list any three characters enclosed dashes and last match in the string

Tags: python, regex, string

My regex finds the three letters enclosed dashes but only returns the first second one in the string

```
(?:-)([A-Z]{3})+?(?:-)
```

I am trying to figure out a regex that finds all three letters enclosed in dashes only thus ignoring the first one `ABC`

```
ABC-FOUR-ONE-FIVE-TWO
```

Can there be a regex that lists only `ONE` and `TWO` (matches all except the first one

Comment: Should `TWO` really be matched if there isn't a trailing `-`?

Comment: You should use find find() rather than matches(). Matches tries to match the entire string against the pattern.

Comment: You probably want something like: [`(?:(?:-)([A-Z]{3})(?:-))+`](https://regex101.com/r/pUCimh/1)

Comment: TWO needs to be matched

Comment: Python implementation

Comment: "TWO needs to be matched" byt why? You stated that you want to only find words which are enclosed with `-` but `TWO` is at the end and it doesn't have `-` after it.

Comment: Did you try your own regex with a dash at the end of the test string?

Comment: "all except the first one" first one (I am assuming you mean `ABC`) will not be matched by your regex since it doesn't have `-` before it. Since that is the case your regex can set regex to accept after word you want `-` OR end of string `$`. So you may be looking something like `(?:-)([A-Z]{3})+?(?:-|$)`.

Comment: `re.findall(r'-([A-Z]{3})(?![^-])', text)`, see a [Python demo](https://ideone.com/yZhtsc).

Comment: It appears you wish to match each string of three letters that is preceded by a hyphen and followed by a hyphen or is at the end of the string. Correct? In any event, you need to edit your question to clarify the requirement.

Answer (score 1):

You may use

```
re.findall(r'-([A-Z]{3})(?![^-])', text)
```

Or, its equivalent

```
re.findall(r'-([A-Z]{3})(?=-|$)', text)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/44OtyM/1) and [Python demo](https://ideone.com/yZhtsc)

**Pattern details**

- `-` - a hyphen
- `([A-Z]{3})` - Capturing group 1: three uppercase letters
- `(?=-|$)` / `(?![^-])` - match (but do not consume) a `-` or end of string position.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this `(-[A-Za-z]{3}(-|$))` (tested it at https://regex101.com/)

This regex says: Match a dash, then 3 [A-Za-z] characters and then finally the "-" character or "end of string"